# Mollifying Green's functions with heat kernel and conformal invariance

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, eigenvalues, quasiconformal

For domain D consider Green's fcn $G_{D}(x,y)$ and heat kernel $H_{D}$ and mollify

$$K_{D}(x,y,t)=\int_{D}\int_{D}H_{D}(x,w,t)H_{D}(u,y,t)G_{D}(w,u)d^{2}wd^{2}u.$$

The green's fcn satisfies $G_{D}(x,y)=G_{f(D)}(f(x),f(y))$ for conformal $f:D\to f(D)$.

**Q1** I am wondering if $K_{D}$ (or some other Green's fcn mollification) satisfies any invariance property for possibly different types of maps.

**Q2** Does $K_{D}$ have any interesting properties? Any papers or books where it was studied?

**Attempts on Q1**

1)By expressing the kernels in  $L^{2}$-basis $\phi_{k}$ and $\nabla-$basis $f_{k}=\phi_{k}/\lambda_{k}^{1/2}$ (i.e. $\int \nabla f_{k}\nabla f_{m}=\delta_{km}$) we have $H_{D}=\sum \phi_{k}(x)\phi_{k}(y)e^{-\lambda_{k}t}$, $G_{D}=\sum f_{k}(x)f_{k}(y)$ and
$$K_{D}(x,y,t)=\sum f_{k}(x)f_{k}(y)e^{-2\lambda_{k}t}.$$

By conformal invariance of $\nabla-$basis we have that $f_{k}^{f(D)}\circ f(x)$ is a $\nabla$ basis for $D$ and so  $G_{D}(x,y)=G_{f(D)}(f(x),f(y))$. However, I think it is still a conjecture that

$$\sum e^{-\lambda_{k}^{f(\mathbb{D})}t}\geq \sum e^{-\lambda_{k}^{\mathbb{D}}t}.$$

2)We want some f(x,t) s.t. $K_{D}(x,y,t)=K_{f(D,t)}(f(x,t),f(y,t),t)$.  One way would be if

$$H_{D}(x,w,t)=H_{f(D,t)}(f(x,t),f(w,t),t)|f'(w)|^{2}.$$

Since the LHS satisfies the heat eqn, one possible constraint for the RHS is $|f'|^{2}=1$ and $f''=f_{t}$. So given at most exponential growth, we have uniqueness and so they are equal.

However, as $t\to 0$ we would like to obtain a conformal map with no constraints on $|f'|^{2}$.